# GitHub not working in Visual Studio Code on Linux but works on Command Line

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

On Ubuntu 18.04. When I try to use GitHub within Visual Studio Code, it says Git:

> git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey):

[image: Problem]

However, everything works well when I use git/GitHub from the Terminal. I have put some SSH keys into GitHub already, and that's why it works from the command line.

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I was running VS Code as root. And the root account did not have access to GitHub, because it had no SSH keys. Only my account had SSH keys generated for GitHub. The solution was to create SSH keys for the root account.

First I had to

```
sudo -i
```

Then, I followed these instructions:

https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.17/user/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent

to generate the SSH key and to add it to the SSH agent and to the GitHub settings.

When all this was done, I was able to connect to GitHub even when running Visual Studio Code as root.